# How to save my Email Messages - Team Services

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, tfsbuild, xunit.net

Ive written some Integration Tests (using XUnit) to test `SmtpClient`. Basically I'm overriding it within my `app.config`

```
configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="F:\EmailTests\"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Now obviously this test fails on Team Services because of the following ref:

> E:\EmailTests

Also this override doesn't except relative paths.

How should these scenarios be handled in TFS where I need to save data during a build?

Comment: If it's interacting with external resources such as the file system, it's not a unit test.

Comment: Let's call it a integration test then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `EmailTests` folder a part of your Unit Test project in Visual Studio, with the `Copy Local` property set to `True`. Doing so provides you with two options:

1. Since the folder is already part of your code-base, it will be checked out by VSO before beginning the build. Then if you need to access it in one of the build tasks, you can use the predefined build variable `Build.SourcesDirectory` and combine it with your folder name like below. You can also use this within your configuration file, replacing the hard-coded `F:\EmailTests\`.

   ```
    $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\EmailTests\
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can access this folder using yet another VSO predefined variable `Build.BinariesDirectory`. However, this will be useful only when the build of the Unit Test project has been completed.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) is a link of all the predefined VSO variables for similar problems.

Comment: This worked for me and pointed me in the right direction to transform my app.config during the build, as I use a different directory during development. The following PS script task before the build. https://gist.github.com/garfbradaz/54645abe0e6005fb43943ac9ba99c9ad